# MySQL updates automatically the date field

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am working on a swing application, and during the test i have faced some problems with updating the data.

i have a table called 'Dose' :

```
create table Dose (id_dose int auto_increment primary key ,
        id_cmd varchar(50),
        t_inj TimeStamp,
        a_inj int,
        id_e_d int,
        id_dose_inc varchar(50),
        poid int ,
        Constraint fkk_et_doses foreign key (id_e_d) references Etat_dose (id_e_d),
        Constraint fkk_et_cmds foreign key (id_cmd) references Commande (id_cmd)ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

the **id_e_d** field references to id_e_d in the **etat_dose** table :

```
create table Etat_dose (id_e_d int primary key,
                    libele varchar(50));
```

and when i insert the data into it, everything works just fine, for that i use the query :

```
Methodes.UpdateData("insert into Dose(id_cmd,t_inj,a_inj,id_e_d,id_dose_inc,poid)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", dose, 6);
```

but when i update the **id_e_d** ,  the **T_inj** in the Dose table changes automatically to the system date. For example :

before when i insert:

```
insert into doses values(1,'CMFDG121031-1',' 2012-10-02 10:30:55',400,1,'CMFDG121031-1-1',30)
```

when i edit it i get :

```
mysql> select * from dose where id_dose=1;
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+------+
    | id_dose | id_cmd        | t_inj               | a_inj | id_e_d | id_dose_inc      | poid 
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+------+
    |       1 | CMFDG121031-1 | 2012-10-02 10:30:55 |   400 |      1 | CMFDG121031-1-1 |   30 |
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------
```

in the update i execute :

```
update dose set id_e_d=2 where id_dose=1
```

i get :

```
   mysql> select * from dose where id_dose=1;
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+------+
    | id_dose | id_cmd        | t_inj               | a_inj | id_e_d | id_dose_inc      | poid 
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-----------------+------+
    |       1 | CMFDG121031-1 | 2012-10-08 16:15:11 |   400 |      2 | CMFDG121031-1-1 |   30 |
    +---------+---------------+---------------------+-------+--------+-------------------------
```

As you can see the values of **T_inj** have been changed automatically. what can i do to track this error down.

Comment: That's the default behaviour of the (first) `timestamp` column of a table.

Answer (score 4):

As documented under [Automatic Initialization and Updating for `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> The `TIMESTAMP` data type offers automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). You can choose whether to use these properties and which column should have them:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - If the column is auto-updated, it is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. The column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent the column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value. To update the column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> The following rules describe the possibilities for defining the first TIMESTAMP column in a table with the current timestamp for both the default and auto-update values, for one but not the other, or for neither:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - With a `DEFAULT` clause but no `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause, the column has the given default value and is not automatically updated to the current timestamp.
>
>   The default depends on whether the `DEFAULT` clause specifies `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or a constant value. With `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, the default is the current timestamp.
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (
>     ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   );
>   ```
>
>   With a constant, the default is the given value. In this case, the column has no automatic properties at all.
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (
>     ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
>   );
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behaviour of the first `timestamp` column of a table. See MySQL docs: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

You can change it with:

```
ALTER TABLE Dose 
  MODIFY COLUMN t_inj TIMESTAMP NULL
           DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE Dose 
  MODIFY COLUMN t_inj TIMESTAMP NULL
           DEFAULT NULL ;
```